# Lpc1347 pwm duty cycle issue

Tags: lpcxpresso

I'd like to write aplication to control PWM with 50Hz frequency and 1ms duty cycle using 16 bit timer. This is my code.

```
#include "board.h"

#include "../../static/inc/ct.h"
#include <cr_section_macros.h>

#define PRESCALE_VAL 36000 /* f = 72MHz, output T = 0.5ms => output f = 2kHz, 72MHz / 2kHZ = 36000 */

#define TIMER LPC_TIMER16_0
#define SYSCTL LPC_SYSCTL
#define IOCON LPC_IOCON

#define PWM_GPIO_PORT 0 /* PWM output port */
#define PWM_GPIO_PIN 8 /* PWM output pin */
#define IOCON_FUNC_PWM IOCON_FUNC2

#define PWM_MATCH_CHANNEL 0
#define PWM_RESET_CHANNEL 3

int main(void) {
 // Generic initialization
 SystemCoreClockUpdate();
 Board_Init();



 IOCON->PIO0[PWM_GPIO_PIN] = IOCON_FUNC_PWM;
 SYSCTL->SYSAHBCLKCTRL |= CT16B0_CLOCK_MASK;
 Timer_Reset(TIMER);
 TIMER->PR = PRESCALE_VAL - 1;
 TIMER->MR[PWM_MATCH_CHANNEL] = 38; // 38 * 0.5 = 19ms
 TIMER->MR[PWM_RESET_CHANNEL] = 40; // 40 * 0.5 = 20ms
 TIMER->MCR |= TIMER_RESET_ON_MATCH(PWM_RESET_CHANNEL);
 TIMER->EMR |= _BIT(PWM_MATCH_CHANNEL);
 TIMER->PWMC |= _BIT(PWM_MATCH_CHANNEL) | _BIT(PWM_RESET_CHANNEL);
 TIMER->TCR |= TIMER_ENABLE_MASK;

 while(1) {}
 return 0 ;
```

}

I'm using logic states analyzer connected to the pwm pin. As a result I see that high state takes exactly 1.5ms (?) and low state takes 19ms (that's ok). My question is why duty cycle takes 1.5ms instead of 1ms?

Comment: I think you may have more success on https://electronics.stackexchange.com.